# Fetching data in a List in SwiftUI

Tags: list, swiftui

I'm trying to create a list of articles about an argument. I created my list mocking my data, everything was ok, but then I tried to create an API call and nothing appears. What am I doing wrong?
This is API I want to use: https://newsapi.org/docs

```
struct NewsListView: View {
    @ObservedObject var newsModel = NewsModel()

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color("whiteBackground").ignoresSafeArea()
            List(newsModel.articles, id: \.url) { article in
                VStack {
                    Text(article.title)
                        .fontWeight(.semibold)
                        .frame(width: 350, height: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                        .foregroundStyle(.black)

                    Text(article.description ?? "")
                        .fontWeight(.light)
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                        .frame(width: 350, height: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                        .foregroundStyle(.black)

                    HStack {
                        Image(systemName: "photo")
                            .resizable()
                            .clipShape(Circle())
                            .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)

                        Text(article.source.name)
                            .fontWeight(.medium)
                            .foregroundStyle(.black)

                        Image(systemName: "clock")
                            .foregroundColor(.black)

                        Text(article.publishedAt)
                            .fontWeight(.thin)
                            .foregroundStyle(.black)
                    }
                    .frame(width: 350, height: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                }
            }
            .onAppear {
                // Fetch data from the API when the view appears
                newsModel.fetchDataFromAPI()
            }
        }
        .frame(width: 380, height: 303)
    }
}

struct Article: Identifiable, Decodable {
    var id = UUID()
    let source: Source
    let author: String?
    let title: String
    let description: String?
    let url: String
    let urlToImage: String?
    let publishedAt: String
    let content: String?
}

struct Source: Decodable {
    let id: String?
    let name: String
}

struct NewsResponse: Decodable {
    let status: String
    let totalResults: Int
    let articles: [Article]
}

#Preview {
    NewsListView()
}
```

Here's my Model:

```
import SwiftUI

class NewsModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var articles: [Article] = []

    func fetchDataFromAPI() {
        let apiKey = "here's my API key"
        let searchQuery = "riciclo"
        let country = "it"
        let language = "it"
        let urlString = "https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?q=\(searchQuery)&country=\(country)&language=\(language)&apiKey=\(apiKey)"

        if let url = URL(string: urlString) {
            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
                if let data = data {
                    do {
                        let response = try JSONDecoder().decode(NewsResponse.self, from: data)
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.articles = response.articles
                        }
                    } catch {
                        print("Error decoding data: \(error)")
                    }
                }
            }.resume()
        }
    }
}
```

I'm just approaching API calls in my App in SwiftUI and I don't get what I'm doing wrong. I think it should be and easy thing but I can't get it. Anyone can help?

Comment: Note, you should be using `@StateObject var newsModel = NewsModel()`
 Also, you could use `List(newsModel.articles)` since `Article` are Identifiable.
 Just after `if let data = data` add `print("\n----> data: \(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) as AnyObject)\n")` and show us what you get from the server. Do you get any errors? if so show the full error message.

Comment: Note, your `struct Article` should have `let id = UUID()` (not var) and the corresponding
 `enum CodingKeys: ...`. Also note, there are no articles regarding
 "riciclo", try "roma". You will also need to adjust the `frame` you use,
 no `height: .infinity`. Apart from that, your code should work.

Comment: Ok, I tried to apply what you said and.. It worked! I mean, I can see "roma" news in debugger, but still it doesn't display it in my view. I tried to fix my frame with a custom height but it didn't worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my code that display the results of a query to the news API server.
Note in particular the modified `Article` struct and the `searchQuery`.
Works well for me, the code displays a number of articles.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NewsListView()
    }
}

struct NewsListView: View {
    @StateObject var newsModel = NewsModel() // <--- here

    var body: some View {
        // for testing
        Text(newsModel.articles.isEmpty ? "no articles" : "\(newsModel.articles.count) articles")
        ZStack {
            Color(.white).ignoresSafeArea()
            List(newsModel.articles) { article in  // <--- here
                VStack {
                    Text(article.title)
                        .fontWeight(.semibold)
                        .frame(width: 350, alignment: .leading) // <--- here
                        .foregroundStyle(.black)

                    Text(article.description ?? "")
                        .fontWeight(.light)
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                        .frame(width: 350, alignment: .leading) // <--- here
                        .foregroundStyle(.black)

                    HStack {
                        Image(systemName: "photo")
                            .resizable()
                            .clipShape(Circle())
                            .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)

                        Text(article.source.name)
                            .fontWeight(.medium)
                            .foregroundStyle(.black)

                        Image(systemName: "clock")
                            .foregroundColor(.black)

                        Text(article.publishedAt)
                            .fontWeight(.thin)
                            .foregroundStyle(.black)
                    }
                    .frame(width: 350, alignment: .leading) // <--- here
                }
            }
            .onAppear {
                // Fetch data from the API when the view appears
                newsModel.fetchDataFromAPI()
            }
        }
        .frame(width: 380, height: 303)
    }
}

struct Article: Identifiable, Decodable {
    let id = UUID()  // <--- here
    
    let source: Source
    let author: String?
    let title: String
    let description: String?
    let url: String
    let urlToImage: String?
    let publishedAt: String
    let content: String?
    
    // --- here, no id
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case source, author, title, description, url, urlToImage, publishedAt, content
    }
}

struct Source: Decodable {
    let id: String?
    let name: String
}

struct NewsResponse: Decodable {
    let status: String
    let totalResults: Int
    let articles: [Article]
}

class NewsModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var articles: [Article] = []

    func fetchDataFromAPI() {
        let apiKey = "here's my API key"
        let searchQuery = "" // <--- here  or "roma" or Milano or just nothing
        let country = "it"
        let language = "it"
        let urlString = "https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?q=\(searchQuery)&country=\(country)&language=\(language)&apiKey=\(apiKey)"

        if let url = URL(string: urlString) {
            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
                // here to print what you get from the server
             // print("\n----> data: \(String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8) as AnyObject)\n")
                if let data = data {
                    do {
                        let response = try JSONDecoder().decode(NewsResponse.self, from: data)
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.articles = response.articles
                        }
                    } catch {
                        print("\n----> data: \(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) as AnyObject)")
                        print("\n----> Error decoding data: \(error) \n")
                        // need to deal with errors <--- todo
                    }
                }
            }.resume()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the most straightforward way is to call the NetworkClient directly from the view and use private state. This is shown below:

```
struct API {
    
    func fetchNews() async throws -> [Article] {
        // code to fetch news
        return []
    }
    
}
```

And the usage is shown below:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    let api: API
    
    @State private var articles: [Article] = []
    
    private func fetchNews() async {
        do {
            articles = try await api.fetchNews()
        } catch {
            // display error
            // log errors
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        List(articles) { article in
            Text(article.title)
        }.task {
            await fetchNews()
        }
        .padding()
        .navigationTitle("News")
    }
}
```

This is suitable for scenarios where you don't want to perform a fetch in other views of the application.